# BFS/IDS Search with Geometric shapes

Tags: search, geometry, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, iterative-deepening

I have a problem I am working on involving breadth first search and iterative deepening search. I understand the search mechanisms for trees but I don't understand how to apply it to grid and geometric shapes. If I wanted to perform a BFS(breadth first search) how would I apply it to this problem where I have to move the pieces so that they would fit perfectly in the square on the right hand side. My attempt is to first take two pieces and place them in the square and then branch out from each side. The problem is, there are many ways I can place the pieces in level 1 of the BFS tree. By looking at the image I know the solution but do not know how I would go about it in terms of the searches

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume from your post history that we are enrolled in the same class and have the same assignment due on Monday.

The way I thought to approach this problem is:

- Case 0 is the empty board
- Case 1 is the multitude of different position that a shape such as the 3x1 could fit in the rectangle
- Case 2 is the multitude of different positions that another shape such as the U shaped one could fit in while taking the 3x1 into account.

As you go on, some shapes aren't going to fit anymore so those branches aren't prolonged anymore.

I haven't figure it out fully, if you want to ponder upon it further or if you have figured out another way to do this, I guess we could 'team up' and try to figure it out.

Comment: For your case 0 and 1 I thought the same thing as well, but since there are a multitude of different ways to branch out on I figured it wasn't the correct way as we can take any 2 pieces to start from and branch out from there.  If you want to get in touch to complete this together, let me know and we can find a way to communicate

Comment: I guess write down your first name and I'll find you on the Moodle. Delete it after if you want to keep anonymity.